# Find $r$,in terms of variables $U$ and $V$

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I want to solve this equation, for $r$:

```
U*V = -Exp[(
 2 (M + M R α + 
    R (-1 + R α)))/((α Sqrt[-1 + 8 M α - 
     2 R α + 3 R^2 α^2]) ( R^2)) * 
 ArcTan[(-1 + 2 r α + R α)/
  Sqrt[-1 + 8 M α - 2 R α + 
   3 R^2 α^2]]]* (r - R) (2 M + r^2 α + 
r (-1 + R α) + R (-1 + R α))^((M + 
R (-1 + R α))/(R^2  α))
```

I need an appropriate command to get $r$ in terms of variables, $U$ and $V$, here α, M, R are arbitrary parameters.   I have tried, `Solve` but it does not work for it. Here is the way I go:

```
a := U V - (-Exp[(2 (M + M R α + 
            R (-1 + R α)))/((α Sqrt[-1 + 8 M α - 2 R α + 
              3 R^2 α^2]) (R^2))*
       ArcTan[(-1 + 2 r α + R α)/
         Sqrt[-1 + 8 M α - 2 R α + 3 R^2 α^2]]] (r - 
      R) (2 M + r^2 α + r (-1 + R α) + 
       R (-1 + R α))^((M + R (-1 + R α))/(R^2 α)))

Solve[a==0,r]
```

output:

> This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve

Comment: `Solve`? Note that `UV` is a single variable, and there are no `U`, no `V` in what you **assign** (`=`) to the variable `UV`.  So you probably need an equation (`==`) first.  But `Solve` is an appropriate command for finding one variable in terms of others.

Comment: Doesn't look like it's solvable by Mathematica.

Comment: This title is of negligible value.  Who in the future will find anything of value in it?

Comment: @ DumpsterDoofus I have tried with Solve command, I worked as follow: a = U*V - ( -Exp[(
       2 (M + M R \[Alpha] + 
          R (-1 + R \[Alpha])))/((\[Alpha] Sqrt[-1 + 8 M \[Alpha] - 
           2 R \[Alpha] + 3 R^2 \[Alpha]^2]) ( R^2)) * 
       ArcTan[(-1 + 2 r \[Alpha] + R \[Alpha])/
        Sqrt[-1 + 8 M \[Alpha] - 2 R \[Alpha] + 
         3 R^2 \[Alpha]^2]]]* (r - R) (2 M + r^2 \[Alpha] + 
      r (-1 + R \[Alpha]) + R (-1 + R \[Alpha]))^((M + 
      R (-1 + R \[Alpha]))/(R^2  \[Alpha])) )$ input: $Solve[a==0,r]$ output:This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve

Comment: @ Michael E2 I have edited the post, U and V are in product not a single variable, sorry for inconvenience. I have tried Solve, but it didnt work.

Comment: @ Yves Klett @ DumpsterDoofus, @ Sjoerd C. de Vries, @ Öskå, @ m_goldberg: I am really sorry if my question does not meet the standard of this site. But I want to let you know that I have worked on it with Solve command, and I get output:This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve , I have tried to find it in already discussed problems as well. I also want to mention that I have edited my question   to remove the confusion of members. I request you to please reconsider my question. Waiting for your kind response.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Please add the relevant info and especially the code from your comments to the question. I think you still have issues with `=` vs `==`.

Comment: @ Yves Klett I have added my attempt in post...I could not get the issue with = vs == I am sorry I am not so expert in Mathematica, I would appreciate if you point out the mistake.

Comment: @ DumpsterDoofus @ Michael E2 If I specify the values of parameters, as /. \[Alpha] -> 0.13 /. Q -> .5^2  /. M -> 1 /. R -> 0.0317520, I am left with $a:= E^(83225. ArcTan[5.60811 (-0.995872 + 0.26 r)]) (-0.031752 + 
    r) (1.96838 - 0.995872 r + 0.13 r^2)^7388.56 + U V $ so now I want Solve[a==0, r]

Comment: Please do not use LaTeX tags (offset with `$`) for code.  Instead use four spaces of indenting.  Reference [editing help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 3):

Given that `U*V = f[r]`, one can invert the function `f` locally about a center, `r == center` in terms of a power series with

```
Normal @ InverseSeries @ Series[f[r], {r, center, orderOfApproximation}] /. r -> U*V
```

This yields a truncated power series (polynomial) that approximates `InverseFunction[f][U*V]`.

For instance,

```
Block[{α = 0.13, Q = 0.5^2, M = 1, R = 0.0317520},
  With[{orderOfApproximation = 3, center = R},
   Normal@ InverseSeries@ Series[-a /. U -> 0, {r, center, orderOfApproximation}] /. r -> U*V
   ]]
(*
  0.031752 - 3.670118311*10^48197 U V - 8.55304118*10^96396 U^2 V^2 - 2.7367133*10^144596 U^3 V^3
*)
```

The series can be used to analyze local behavior in the neighborhood of the center.

As noted in the comments and by `Solve` itself, it is not known by me, *Mathematica* and a few others how to solve this equation in finite terms.  The variable `r` appears as a factor, an exponent, and the base of an exponential.

---

One can try to differentiate the equation and see if the integration algorithms might recognize the solution as a standard function.  They're not likely to, and they don't.  With `DSolve`, we get a solution, though, and it's in terms of `InverseFunction`.  Unfortunately, solution never finished trying to evaluate when I plugged in `U -> 0`.  I suspect part of the problem is that the value of `U*V` is extremely small; say for `0 < r < R`, it is on the order `10^-48200` for the parameter settings `{α = 0.13, Q = 0.5^2, M = 1, R = 0.0317520}`.

To get the differential equation in terms of just two variables, we replace `U*V` by just `U` (by setting `V -> 1`).

`DSolve` cannot solve the equation with the approximate parameters before I get impatient and kill it.  Neither can it solve the equation with exact coefficients because the coefficients of the differential equation get too large for `PolynomialGCD`. It can solve general equation with symbolic coefficients, but not the initial value problem.  By inspection, one can see that the IVP is equivalent to `C[1] -> 0`.  One can substitute some of the parameter values before integration and some after to get a solution `sol` in terms of the parameters.  It appears to be academic, though, unless you can get the resulting `InverseFunction` to evaluate.

```
df = D[-a /. V -> 1 /. r -> r[U], U];

{sol} = DSolve[{df == 0(*, r[0] == R*)}, r, U] /. C[1] -> 0

Block[{α = 13/100, Q = 1/4, M = 1(*, R = 317520/10000000*)},
 {sol} = DSolve[{df == 0(*, r[0] == R*)}, r, U] /. R -> 317520/10000000 /. C[1] -> 0
 ]
```

One can get a numeric approximation, if we scale `U*V` by `10^-48200` to bring the computation into the range of machine floating-point numbers.  We also get rid of unimportant factors from the differential equation (at some point, they were interfering with the numerics).

```
df = SelectFirst[
   List @@ Factor@D[-a /. V -> 1/10^48200 /. r -> r[U], U], !FreeQ[#, Derivative] &];

Block[{α = 13/100, Q = 1/4, M = 1, R = 317520/10000000},
 {sol} = NDSolve[{df == 0, r[0] == R}, r, {U, -3, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
 ]
```

> NDSolve::ndsz: At U == 1.9200495476454491656923239602150905184576238140407707627394`20., step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>

```
Plot[r[U] /. sol, Evaluate@Flatten[{U, r["Domain"] /. sol}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If the plot is sufficient, it's easier to flip the plot of the inverse function with

```
Block[{α = 0.13, Q = 0.5^2, M = 1, R = 0.0317520},
 Show[
  Plot[-10^48200 a /. U -> 0, {r, 0.011, 0.039}, AxesOrigin -> {0.01, 0.}] /.
   {x_Real, y_Real} :> {y, x}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
 ]
```

Comment: @ Michael E2 I want to say you thanks for such a comprehensive explanation, I see that this is really giving tough time to get r (at least explicitly). I appreciate your efforts, but if we have to chose r as general, I means without restriction that r< R, because here 0<r<infinity. The second thing is, I have to use this equation with another differential equation dV/dU== fuction[U, V, r], So if I give some initial value of U and V and get r from the resulting equation, then I will use that r in the differential equation to get solution $V$, so its not the matter of just fixing one V and U.

Comment: @ Michael E2 If you do not mind could I please share my differential equation with you, I am trying to solve, that is linked to this equation in fact.