# How to use a numerical integral as an input function

Tags: numerical-integration, scoping

I am new to *mathematica*. I am trying to use a numerical indefinite integral as an input function of a module.

I have a function 
$$r^* \equiv r^*(r)=\int_0^{1/r} B(z)dz$$ with $B(z)$ being a analytic but sophisticated function. The above function is defined in *mathematica* as a numerical indefinite integral as follows

```
rStar[r_] := 
 NIntegrate[B[z1],{z1, 0, 1/r}, WorkingPrecision -> MyPrecision, MaxRecursion -> MyRecursion]
```

The reason to use ":=", as I understand is because that the *NIntegrate* asks all input to be numerical, so the expression should only be replaced when the function rStar[] is evoked with a numerical value of r.

Now what I need is the inverse function $r(r^*)$, for given value of $r^*$. So I make use of a module which uses bisection method to find the root of $r*(r)=r*$ as follows

```
NRootFinder[Function_, {var_, neg_, pos_}, precision_] := 
 Module[{oldm = neg, n = neg, p = pos, m = (neg + pos)/2, f, g = 10^(-precision)},
  While[Abs[n - p] > g && oldm != m,
   oldm = m;
   f = Re[Function /. var -> m];
   If[f > 0, p = m, If[f < 0, n = m, Break[]]];
   m = (n + p)/2;
  ];
  {var -> m}
 ];
```

and defines

```
Tortuga[x_, aa_, bb_, MyPrecision_] := 
 NRootFinder[ SetPrecision[rStar[r] - x, MyPrecision], 
  {r, SetPrecision[aa, MyPrecision], SetPrecision[bb, MyPrecision]}, MyPrecision]
```

NRootFinder and Tortuga work fine for any given function other than rStar[], and rStar[] works just fine for any numerical input such as rStar[0.1]. The combination, however, does not work. As I understand, *mathematica* requires some numerical input instead of symbolic r in *NIntegrate* even when the module is define. The error message was

```
NIntegrate::nlim: "z1 = 1/r is not a valid limit of integration. "
```

Is it possible to achieve the above goal in a correct and elegant way? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You certainly can do `rStar[r_?NumericQ] := (* stuff *)` to mitigate your problem, but it seems to me you could do better by using `NDSolve[]` with `WhenEvent[]` if it's really the root you are interested in and not the function itself.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: For more on `?NumericQ`, see [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037).

Comment: [This answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71474/find-r-in-terms-of-variables-u-and-v/71508#71508) shows a variety of approaches, including the use of `NDSolve` to compute the inverse of a function.

Comment: Many thanks. ?NumericQ seems to work! Concerning `NDSolve`, I read the post and thought about it, still I don't get it. How to get the inverse function by solving a differential equation? I tried google but did not get much information. Are there other post with a simple example?

Comment: I see, NDSolve the derivative of rStar equals to the inverse of the derivative of inverse function. In my case, probably it wont work, since the original function rStar contains up to 16th higher order polinomial as well as operations such as square root, so I guess the computational time is not affordable. I will give it a try anyway.

Comment: I tried to use `NDSolve`, but then encountered the problem of infinity. After some tentative guess, am not able to get through. I think it is a quite different situation now, so I started a new question.